# I can't see my script files in chrome developer?

Tags: google-chrome, typescript

I'm writing some typescripts in visual studio and they build/compile run fine- only when I open chrome developer tools I can only see 1 of the files, but there are three...

How can I get chrome developer to show all my files?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are including the files in your page via script tags? Chrome dev tools should show all of the scripts included in your pages. Assuming you are generating .js.map files, it should show both the JS and TS files.